# getBoolean won't accept string key with getSharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, boolean, sharedpreferences

This might be Android 101, but I'm getting used to the SDK now.  Anyhow, I simply do not understand the error.  I want to update some checkbox selections based on my shared preferences file and I'm using the following method:

```
private void updatePreferencesData() {

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

    Boolean textData = prefs.getBoolean(R.string.Chri, false);
    CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkbxChristmas);
    cb1.setChecked(textData);

}
```

Android Studio doesn't like my use of R.string.Chri in  Boolean textData = prefs.getBoolean(R.string.Chri, false);

It states: "getBoolean(java.lang.String, Boolean) in SharedPreferences cannot be applied to (int, Boolean)"

In my strings.xml  I have the value:

```
<string name="Chri">Christmas</string>
```

When I simply change the line to

```
 Boolean textData = prefs.getBoolean("Christmas", false);
```

It works fine

How is it that the strings in strings.xml is being handled differently?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Android Studio doesn't like my use of R.string.Chri in Boolean textData = prefs.getBoolean(R.string.Chri, false);

Correct. `R.string.Chri` is an `int`. To get a string, call `getString(R.string.Chri)` on some `Context`, such as your activity.

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
 prefs.getBoolean(this.getResources().getString(R.string.Chri), false);
```

Answer (score 2):

`R.string.Chri` is an int. Instead use `getResources().getString(R.string.Chri)` to retrieve the string.